# Get the angle of an edge

Tags: python

I need to know the angle of an edge using `bpy`. I need this angle in the x-y plane so if the edge is aligned with the Y axis the angle will be 1.57 radiants (90 degree) and if the edge is aligned with the X axis the angle will be 0. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The raw answer is

```
import bpy
from mathutils import *
from math import *

v1 = Vector([3,2,0])
v2 = Vector([3,2,1])
C = v2-v1

theta = atan2(C[1], C[0])

print(theta)
```

If you need to be able to compute this from the currently selected edge of a mesh, let me know and I can upgrade the python.

Comment: With `v1 = Vector([1,1,0])` and `v2 = Vector([2,2,0])` should give me 0.78 rad (45°) but give me back 0.0. Thanks anyway!

Comment: OK, i was thinking "from the XY plane" , not "in the XY plane", fixed.

Comment: Thanks , I was also trying with `angle(other, fallback)` but the angle was always absolute. Your is a much better way.